# Using bluepy to send and read serial data

Tags: python, bluetooth

I am trying to use bluepy to write and read serial data to/from an HC-08 Bluetooth module. The HC-08 is connected to a device that returns a fixed number of bytes whenever it receives a message over the HC-08.

Below is my code so far. This seems to work—however, I kind of winged this code from examples and an a lot of trial and error. I am not entirely sure what I am doing. Therefore, any comments/feedback for potential improvements would be very welcome. The code is implemented as a `class myhc08` that has a `write` method. This method writes a string to the hc08 and then reads out a set number of bytes.

```
import struct
import bluepy.btle as btle
from matplotlib import pyplot

class ReadDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = b''
        
    def reset(self):
        self.data = b''
    
    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        self.data = self.data + data
    
    @property
    def data_length(self):
        return len(self.data)

class myHC08:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mac = '34:14:B5:50:34:77'
        self.write_service_id = 4
        self.write_service = None
        self.peripheral = btle.Peripheral(self.mac)
        self.delegate = ReadDelegate()
        self.peripheral.withDelegate(self.delegate)
        
    def connect(self):
        s = self.write_service_id
        services = self.peripheral.getServices()
        self.write_service = self.peripheral.getServiceByUUID(list(services)[s].uuid)
    
    def write(self, message, min_bytes, unpack_string=False):
        print('Writing:', message)
        self.delegate.reset()
        c = self.write_service.getCharacteristics()[0]
        c.write(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
        print('Receiving %i bytes' % min_bytes)
        while self.peripheral.waitForNotifications(1): pass
        while self.delegate.data_length < min_bytes: pass
        received = self.delegate.data
        if unpack_string: received = struct.unpack(unpack_string,received)
        return received
        
    def disconnect(self):
        self.peripheral.disconnect()
    


bt = myHC08()
bt.connect()
r = bt.write('1*', 1250*2, '1250H')
bt.disconnect()
```

In case this helps, my computer lists the following UUIDs for the HC-08 device:

```
00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Generic Access
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Generic Attribute
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Device Information
0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Unknown
0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Unknown
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Answer (score 4):

### Concatenation

In computer science terms, depending on a lot of things, this:

```
    self.data = self.data + data
```

can be worst-case O(n^2). This happens when the Python runtime needs to work reallocating everything in the existing buffer before it's able to add new data. One way around this is to use `BytesIO` instead.

### Casting to a list

Based on the [documentation](https://ianharvey.github.io/bluepy-doc/peripheral.html):

> getServices() / Returns a list of Service objects

Since it's already a list, there is no need to re-cast to a `list` here:

```
    self.write_service = self.peripheral.getServiceByUUID(list(services)[s].uuid)
```

### Disconnection safety

Since `myHC08` has a `disconnect` method, it should be made into a context manager, and used in a `with` statement; or at the least:

```
bt.connect()
try:
    r = bt.write('1*', 1250*2, '1250H')
finally:
    bt.disconnect()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will implement these suggestions. Thanks for catching those.